# Xen 3.2 on Lenny network bridge broken

Tags: networking, virtualization, xen, bridge, debian-lenny

I've upgraded recently a server of mine that was running Debian Etch as Xen Dom0 to Lenny. Now the Ubuntu DomU machine running on it has lost all network connectivity except with the Dom0. I use network bridging for them.

I have checked out most places I could have slipped, but without luck. How can I identify the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved by removing the bridge=xenbr0 statement from the following line in the virtual hosts's config file:

```
vif = [ 'ip=xxxxx, mac=xxxx, bridge=xenbr0' ]
```